# Installing ERPNext on Ubuntu 20.0.4. SIGTERM being sent to Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, erpnext, frappe

I am following [this tutorial](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-erpnext-erp-system-on-ubuntu/), to install [ERPNext](https://erpnext.com/) on my Ubuntu 20.0.4 LTS OS.

I managed to follow all the instructions, however, when I run `bench start`, the system fails to start.

Here is the console output:

```
WARN: bench is installed in editable mode!

This is not the recommended mode of installation for production. Instead, install the package from PyPI with: `pip install frappe-bench`

10:26:19 system           | redis_cache.1 started (pid=11096)
10:26:19 system           | redis_queue.1 started (pid=11097)
10:26:19 system           | redis_socketio.1 started (pid=11095)
10:26:19 redis_socketio.1 | 11105:C 24 May 2022 10:26:19.200 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
10:26:19 system           | socketio.1 started (pid=11100)
10:26:19 redis_queue.1    | 11106:C 24 May 2022 10:26:19.205 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
10:26:19 system           | web.1 started (pid=11098)
10:26:19 redis_queue.1    | 11106:C 24 May 2022 10:26:19.208 # Redis version=5.0.7, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=11106, just started
10:26:19 redis_queue.1    | 11106:C 24 May 2022 10:26:19.208 # Configuration loaded
10:26:19 redis_queue.1    | 11106:M 24 May 2022 10:26:19.209 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 1024).
10:26:19 redis_queue.1    | 11106:M 24 May 2022 10:26:19.217 * Running mode=standalone, port=11000.
10:26:19 redis_cache.1    | 11103:C 24 May 2022 10:26:19.223 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
10:26:19 redis_cache.1    | 11103:C 24 May 2022 10:26:19.224 # Redis version=5.0.7, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=11103, just started
10:26:19 redis_cache.1    | 11103:C 24 May 2022 10:26:19.224 # Configuration loaded
10:26:19 redis_cache.1    | 11103:M 24 May 2022 10:26:19.225 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 1024).
10:26:19 system           | watch.1 started (pid=11099)
10:26:19 redis_socketio.1 | 11105:C 24 May 2022 10:26:19.229 # Redis version=5.0.7, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=11105, just started
10:26:19 redis_socketio.1 | 11105:C 24 May 2022 10:26:19.229 # Configuration loaded
10:26:19 redis_socketio.1 | 11105:M 24 May 2022 10:26:19.230 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 1024).
10:26:19 redis_socketio.1 | 11105:M 24 May 2022 10:26:19.231 * Running mode=standalone, port=12000.
10:26:19 system           | worker_short.1 started (pid=11113)
10:26:19 system           | schedule.1 started (pid=11115)
10:26:19 redis_cache.1    | 11103:M 24 May 2022 10:26:19.243 * Running mode=standalone, port=13000.
10:26:19 redis_cache.1    | 11103:M 24 May 2022 10:26:19.244 # Server initialized
10:26:19 redis_cache.1    | 11103:M 24 May 2022 10:26:19.244 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
10:26:19 redis_cache.1    | 11103:M 24 May 2022 10:26:19.244 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
10:26:19 redis_cache.1    | 11103:M 24 May 2022 10:26:19.244 * Ready to accept connections
10:26:19 redis_queue.1    | 11106:M 24 May 2022 10:26:19.247 # Server initialized
10:26:19 redis_queue.1    | 11106:M 24 May 2022 10:26:19.248 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
10:26:19 redis_queue.1    | 11106:M 24 May 2022 10:26:19.248 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
10:26:19 redis_queue.1    | 11106:M 24 May 2022 10:26:19.248 * Ready to accept connections
10:26:19 redis_socketio.1 | 11105:M 24 May 2022 10:26:19.248 # Server initialized
10:26:19 redis_socketio.1 | 11105:M 24 May 2022 10:26:19.248 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
10:26:19 redis_socketio.1 | 11105:M 24 May 2022 10:26:19.249 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
10:26:19 redis_socketio.1 | 11105:M 24 May 2022 10:26:19.249 * Ready to accept connections
10:26:19 system           | worker_long.1 started (pid=11118)
10:26:19 system           | worker_default.1 started (pid=11124)
10:26:21 socketio.1       | listening on *: 9000
10:26:23 schedule.1       | WARN: bench is installed in editable mode!
10:26:23 schedule.1       |
10:26:23 schedule.1       | This is not the recommended mode of installation for production. Instead, install the package from PyPI with: `pip install frappe-bench`
10:26:23 schedule.1       |
10:26:23 web.1            | WARN: bench is installed in editable mode!
10:26:23 web.1            |
10:26:23 web.1            | This is not the recommended mode of installation for production. Instead, install the package from PyPI with: `pip install frappe-bench`
10:26:23 web.1            |
10:26:23 watch.1          | WARN: bench is installed in editable mode!
10:26:23 watch.1          |
10:26:23 watch.1          | This is not the recommended mode of installation for production. Instead, install the package from PyPI with: `pip install frappe-bench`
10:26:23 watch.1          |
10:26:26 watch.1          |
10:26:26 web.1            |  * Running on all addresses.
10:26:26 web.1            |    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
10:26:26 web.1            |  * Running on http://[PUBLIC_IP_ADDRESS]:8000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
10:26:26 web.1            |  * Restarting with stat
10:26:27 web.1            |  * Debugger is active!
10:26:27 web.1            |  * Debugger PIN: 214-927-934
10:26:28 watch.1          | yarn run v1.22.18
10:26:28 watch.1          | $ node esbuild --watch --live-reload
10:26:30 watch.1          | clean: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
10:26:30 watch.1          | https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
10:26:35 system           | worker_short.1 stopped (rc=1)
10:26:35 system           | sending SIGTERM to redis_cache.1 (pid 11096)
10:26:35 system           | sending SIGTERM to redis_socketio.1 (pid 11095)
10:26:35 system           | sending SIGTERM to redis_queue.1 (pid 11097)
10:26:35 system           | sending SIGTERM to web.1 (pid 11098)
10:26:35 system           | sending SIGTERM to socketio.1 (pid 11100)
10:26:35 system           | sending SIGTERM to watch.1 (pid 11099)
10:26:35 system           | sending SIGTERM to schedule.1 (pid 11115)
10:26:35 system           | sending SIGTERM to worker_long.1 (pid 11118)
10:26:35 system           | sending SIGTERM to worker_default.1 (pid 11124)
10:26:35 redis_cache.1    | 11103:signal-handler (1653387995) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
10:26:35 redis_cache.1    | 11103:M 24 May 2022 10:26:35.885 # User requested shutdown...
10:26:35 redis_cache.1    | 11103:M 24 May 2022 10:26:35.885 * Removing the pid file.
10:26:35 redis_cache.1    | 11103:M 24 May 2022 10:26:35.885 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
10:26:35 system           | redis_queue.1 stopped (rc=-15)
10:26:35 system           | worker_default.1 stopped (rc=-15)
10:26:35 system           | redis_socketio.1 stopped (rc=-15)
10:26:35 system           | redis_cache.1 stopped (rc=-15)
10:26:35 system           | socketio.1 stopped (rc=-15)
10:26:35 system           | schedule.1 stopped (rc=-15)
10:26:36 system           | web.1 stopped (rc=-15)
10:26:36 system           | watch.1 stopped (rc=-15)
```

What is causing this issue, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that they are errors in the latest versions of the bench installer, it has happened to me in some VPS.

1. The first is a problem with the Transparent Huge Pages (THP), you have to disable them, I suggest you create a service that checks that they are disabled during boot and keep them that way, or try this option:
   https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-big-sql/5.0.4?topic=sql-disabling-transparent-hugepages
2. You also have a problem with the number of files to watch, you can solve it with this:

`sudo vim /etc/sysctl.conf`

fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
vm.overcommit_memory = 1

Check:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

It should appear something like this:

```
fs.file-max = 65535
vm.swappiness = 10
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 524288
```

Remember to restart.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is strictly an [English Q&A only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange). Posts containing anything else risk being [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Please translate your answer to English only.